# Vigenere cipher code in C

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc,  string argv[])
{

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("One more string \n");
    }
    string key = argv[1];
    else if(!isalpha(key))
    {
        printf("Prompt only alphabet letters\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        string p = GetString();

        for ( i=0, j=0, n=strlen(p); i<p; i++, j++)
        { 
            if(j>=stlrlen(p))
            {
                j=0;
            }

            if(isupper(p[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((p[i] +key[j])%26)+'A');
            }

            if(islower(p[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((p[i] + key[j])%26)+'a');
            }

            if(!isupper(p[i]) && !islower(p[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", p[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? CS50 Appliance brings me 1 error

```
c:15:1 expected expression.
```

Does it make any sense in my code?
Can someone help me?
When I'm just deleting else if block of code, it brings me the same error to else statement further.

Comment: The first `else` has no corresponding `if`. Did you mean to include `string key = argv[1];` in one of the blocks?

Comment: You can't have code outside of the scope of the if or else in between the if-else

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you cannot have a statement split up an `if` and `else if` or `if` and `else`

```
if(argc!=2)
{
    printf("One more string \n");
}
string key = argv[1]; // This is the problem ➞ it cannot sit in the middle of if and else or else if
else if(!isalpha(key))
{
    printf("Prompt only alphabet letters\n");
}
```

Furthermore, you probably mean to make the `else if` and the `else` regular `if` statements because it looks like you are doing some validation

Also, since you in your for-loop you have `i<p` but `p` is a string. Furthermore, since you don't update `n` in the loop you should initialize it outside

```
int n = strlen( p );
for (int i=0, j=0; i<n; i++, j++)
```

Also despite declaring n and assigning it `strlen( p )`, you use the function call inside your for-loop. There's nothing wrong with that, it just might make more sense to use the variable you assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have code between an if and an else if statement.

`string key = argv[1];` cannot be there